# Mapbox Share Style - Make Public button not working?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm trying to transfer a style between Mapbox accounts, following Approach 1 on this Mapbox documentation:
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/transfer-styles-between-accounts/

However, when I click the Make Public button, and confirm that I want to Make Public, nothing happens. The modal window closes but the style is not public. If I try again, the same Make Public button appears, I click it, nothing happens.

According to the video that accompanies Approach 1, the Make Public button should turn into an Allow Copying link after I've confirmed.

Am I missing something, or is there a bug in Mapbox Studio? Is anyone else experiencing the same?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, contact Mapbox directly. They are usually quite responsive and helpful.

Comment: Is this issue still occurring?

Comment: Thanks for following up. The issue has resolved itself without me doing anything. I assume there was a temporary bug in the system.